# HashMap String and Count number of times each word is used

Tags: java, hashmap, concurrenthashmap

The question below is in Java

Sample data : https://tartarus.org/martin/PorterStemmer/output.txt

I have a tokenizationString String array that contain words that similar to the list above with many duplicated words.

I have to conver that string array into a hashmap and then use the hashmap to count the number of times each word is used (count the duplicated value in the string array but i have to use hashmap related method) .

I am thinking of doing in this way

```
Map<Integer, String> hashMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();    
            for(int i = 0 ; i < tokenizationString.length; i++)
                {
                   hashMap.put(i, tokenizationString[i]);

                }
```

After that I will have to sort the string array by # of time they are used.

In the end I want to be able to print out the result like:

```
the "was used" 502 "times"
i "was used" 50342 "times"
apple "was used" 50 "times"
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, your map should be like `Map<String, Integer>`(string and its frequency).
I am giving you the Java 8 stream solution.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("out.txt"))) {
        Map<String, Long> frequency = lines
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        Map.Entry::getKey,
                        Map.Entry::getValue,
                        (o, n) -> o,
                        LinkedHashMap::new
                ));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Above code will read from file line by line. Then collect as a frequency map. Then again convert them into stream of `entrySet`. Then sort the stream based on the value in reverse order. Lastly collect them as a [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html). `LinkedHashMap` because it will maintain the insersion order. Take look at Java 8 Stream API.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
hashMap.put(i, tokenizationString[i]);
```

first check if the word is already present, and then increment the corresponding entry:

```
int count = hashMap.containsKey(tokenizationString[i]) ? hashMap.get(tokenizationString[i]) : 0;
hashMap.put(tokenizationString[i], count + 1);
```

Comment: Hi I have tried it but the code doesn't work. Did u write it in Java? 
I made change to the code above into 

 Map<String, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

and it works. So the hashmap will have the structure of  <String,Integer>

String : is the key of the map
Integer : is the number of time that key repeating.

Comment: Yes, you need to keep string as key for the hashmap, and the count as the value.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by Google [Gauva library](https://github.com/google/guava)'s MultiMap class as below. Also find the working example at this link - https://gist.github.com/dkalawadia/8d06fba1c2c87dd94ab3e803dff619b0

```
FileInputStream fstream = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        fstream = new FileInputStream("C:\\temp\\output.txt");
         br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));

        String strLine;

        Multimap<String, String> multimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
        // Read File Line By Line
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            multimap.put(strLine, strLine);
        }

        for (String key : multimap.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(key + "was used " + multimap.get(key).size() + "times");
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (fstream != null) {
            fstream.close();
        }
        if(br!=null){
            br.close();
        }
    }
```